# Is there a possibility for an AI to make the skee ball machine to act like cannons?

Tags: technology, artificial-intelligence

As you can see, the AI went into the skee ball machine and turned them into cannons.  The diagram below shows how the ring of the machine becomes a cone-like shape.  **I believe there are many tiny motors built in to make a cone-like shape that is more flexible.**  *When the machine shoots, the shape's height gets shorter and the length gets longer.  And then the height and length of the shape get reverted.*  There must be a built-in machine that shoots the skee balls from the hole.  *The speed of the ball is similar to someone throwing it at you or a tennis ball machine.*  The balls are a little smaller than the regular skee balls.  **I just want to clarify if the skee ball cannon is a possibility and if enough motors would make the cone-like shape more flexible.** 
[image: Skee ball 'cannon']

Comment: Anything is possible if you completely redesign the skee-ball machine from the ground up with the expressed purpose of  being a cannon.  Or, if you want to phrase it more meaningfully, it is possible to camouflage a cannon as a skee ball machine.

Comment: If a human could do it, so could an AI.

Comment: I imagine nanotechnology being a possibility.

Answer (score 6):

No, an artificial intelligence could not turn the target of a skee ball machine into a cannon.

Since the target of a skee ball machine has no motors in it. There is no way for anything to modify the target to launch balls without physically adding a launching mechanism to it.

All an AI would be able to do would be mess with the display and the score.

Comment: I did mention that there are many tiny motors within the set of rings.  Nanites could go inside of the rings and build tiny motors to make it into a cone-like shape and more flexible.

Comment: Another thing I want to clarify: is there a possibility with enough motors, the machine would have more flexibility?

Comment: @AnonymousInquirer Sure why not. It wouldn't really be a skee ball machine at that point. I'm not sure how an AI inhabiting the machine would be able to modify it in such a way.

Comment: I did say there are tiny motors in the ring of the skee ball machine.  The skee ball machine has been modified by the AI.

Answer (score 2):

If however, the AI runs a factory which creates skee ball machines, it could design and build a skee ball machine with a collapsible cannon in the target.  There doesn't seem to be any technical difficulties with your design, it just would require advanced fabrication well in advance of the desired firing date.

Alternatively, if your AI is running the virtual reality in which your proposed target is playing skee ball...   then all bets are off.

Comment: Not trying to be too realistic, but I understand your comment.